# Using Apache Spark and OpenCV for image analysis

Tags: apache-spark, opencv, pyspark

I want to do some image analysis on a large amount of images (thousands) and I want to try to use Spark to speed this up. For testing purposes I am using docker compose to setup a standalone cluster locally.

I want to do some basic analysis such as computing gradients, edge detection, etc. 
I can successfully load my images into a dataframe using:

```
images = spark.read.format("image").option("dropInvalid", True).load("/opt/spark-data/")
```

I tried to call OpenCV functions such as Sobel, using udf. But I am unable to load the image data into a format that OpenCV can work with.

Is there any way I can convert the image data in a way such that I can use OpenCV functions? Or are there better ways to do this than using OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work from help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611888/how-is-spark-reading-my-image-using-the-image-format).

```
def convertImageGeneric( image, fa , down_width = 500, down_height = 500):
 import numpy as np
 import cv2
 fa = cv2.SIFT_create(400)
 cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(
       np.reshape(image.data, (image.height, image.width, image.nChannels)), # this handles the image conversion
       cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY
      )
 preds = fa.detect( image , None )
 return (image.origin, Vectors.dense(no_more_numpy(preds)) )
```

Comment: Thank! It's Just what I was looking for. I Reduced the function ever more to generalice i:.

import numpy as np
import cv2

def convertImageGeneric( image,color_scheme=cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB):
    return cv2.cvtColor(
       np.reshape(image.data, (image.height, image.width, image.nChannels)),color_scheme )